# Defining a cone in cartesian closed categories

Tags: category-theory

My research area is on cartesian closed categories. I want to use both Kock's and Sukhinin's papers to help me obtain my results in cartesian closed categories. I am however unable to define a cone in cartesian closed categories. Defining a cone will help me come up with the definiton of a derivative in cartesian closed categories which will hence give many interesting application. Kindly give me an insight. I will appreciate any references.

Comment: What do you mean by cone? As in the cones and cocones used in the categorical construction of limits and colimits?

Comment: If you're using the usual category theory definition of "cone", I'm not sure what would be special about Cartesian closed categories. You may want to elaborate on what you're looking for.